# Let div overlapping a div overlap a div

Tags: html, css, position

I have an old structure here I managed to solve by creating DIV A1 absolute and some other stuff, but I don't like that solution anymore. There must be something better nowadays.

It is important that the structure in this example is NOT changed.

Question:

- DIV A and DIV B are wo DIVs
- DIV B1 is inside DIV B
- DIV B1 should overlap DIV A. Can be achieved with negative margin and relative position or something like that.
- DIV A1 is inside DIV A
- DIV A2 is inside DIV A1 and is something like a selectlist

Question
When the selectlist opens it should overlap DIV B1

```css
.body {
  background-color: #eee;
}
.d {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}
.a {
  background-color: #f00;
}
.b {
  background-color: #00ff0036;
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.a1 {
  background-color: #0ff;
  width: 70%;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}
.a2 {
  background-color: #8dd7b8;
  width: 70%;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}
.b1 {
  background-color: #003cffb0;
  width: 70%;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: -60px;
}
```

```html
<div class="body">
  <div class="a d">A
    <div class="a1">A1
      <div class="a2">
        This DIV A2 needs to overlap the blue DIV B1.<br />At the moment it is under DIV B1.<br />While DIV B1 should keep overlapping DIV A.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="b d">B
    <div class="b1">B1

    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

An image showing desired end result:

[image]

Comment: Why can't you just use `z-index: 99` in `.a2`

Answer (score 0):

Already 99% is answered by you. You just need to add `z-index: 10` to `.a2`. Since it should be an front element. 
The `z-index` property specifies the stack order of an element, An element with greater stack order is always in front of an element with a lower stack order.

```css
.body {
  background-color: #eee;
}
.d {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}
.a {
  background-color: #f00;
}
.b {
  background-color: #00ff0036;
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.a1 {
  background-color: #0ff;
  width: 70%;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}
.a2 {
  z-index: 10;
  background-color: #8dd7b8;
  width: 70%;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}
.b1 {
  background-color: #003cffb0;
  width: 70%;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: -60px;
}
```

```html
<div class="body">
  <div class="a d">A
    <div class="a1">A1
      <div class="a2">
        This DIV A2 needs to overlap the blue DIV B1.<br />At the moment it is under DIV B1.<br />While DIV B1 should keep overlapping DIV A.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="b d">B
    <div class="b1">B1

    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Problem is creating an abstract of the actual situation. I need to update the example, because only adding z-index to a2 is of course not working on the original. Will try to update it as soon as possible.

Comment: @Mike Once you updated, mention me. I will try and learn